# Two Within-Subject Repeated Measures ANOVA in Python

Tags: python, anova, mixed-models

thanks in advance for the help!
I am trying to run a repeated measures ANOVA in Python. I have one between-subject factor ("Genotype") and two within-subject factors ("Day" & "Cue").

I have tried using pingouin (both rm_anova and mixed_anova) and the code fails:

```
rep_aov= pg.mixed_anova(dv='Att', between='Genotype', within=['Day', 'Cue'], subject='Subject', data=sg100)
```

When I run the anova with only one within-subject factor, it works -- i.e.,:

```
rep_aov= pg.mixed_anova(dv='Att', between='Genotype', within='Day', subject='Subject', data=sg100)
```

How can I get this to work with two within-subject factors? Maybe mixed_anova is not the correct function? Any info would be great!

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/raphaelvallat/pingouin/issues/182#issuecomment-870436291, it's not possible with pingouin currently. You can use R packages as the example in that post.